# Open neighborhoods in $R^2$ and corresponding open neighborhoods in $X$

Tags: general-topology

I've been given two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ on a topological space $X$ where $f,g:X \to \Bbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric and must show $f + g$ is continuous. I am making two intermediate functions $a$ and $b$, where $a: X \to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined as $a(x)=(f(x), g(x))$ and $b:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $b(x,y) = x + y$. I am trying to show that $a$ is continuous, but I am confused about how to show the preimage of an open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ is open using the continuity of $f$ and$ g$.

Once I show $a$ and $b$ are continuous I will show their composition is continuous as required.

Comment: Do you have to prove it this way? Or could you show that $h = f+g$ is such that $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ for any open subset $U \subset \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: I am following an outline that suggested using the continuity of a composition of continuous functions, but if there is a way to show f+g is continuous some other way I'd be happy

Answer (score 1):

If $R^2$ has the product topology (which it does in your case), you can use the convenient fact that a function $h$ from a topological space $X$ to $R \times R$ (or to any finite product of topological spaces for that matter) is continuous if and only if the composition of $h$ with each projection map is continuous. That is, if $\pi_1: R \times R \rightarrow R$ is the projection onto the first coordinate and $\pi_2$ is the projection onto the second, $h: X \rightarrow R \times R$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_1 \circ h$ and $\pi_2 \circ h$ are continuous. In your case this is given to you since $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be continuous, so once you prove the continuity of $b$, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

you must show $f^{-1}((a,b)\times(c,d))=g^{-1}(a,b)\cap h^{-1}(c,d)$is open and it is clear because h and g is continuous and intersection of two open set is open